# How to create verification email with codeigniter 3

Tags: php, arrays, count, controller, codeigniter-3

```php
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    // Load model
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }

    // Halaman login
    public function index()
    {

        // Validasi
        $valid = $this->form_validation;

        $valid->set_rules('username','Username','required',
            array(  'required'      => 'Username harus diisi'));

        $valid->set_rules('password','Password','required|min_length[6]',
            array(  'required'      => 'Password harus diisi',
                    'min_length'    => 'Password minimal 6 karakter'));

        if($valid->run()=== FALSE) {
        // End validasi 

        $data = array(  'title'     => 'Login Administrator');
        $this->load->view('admin/login_view', $data, FALSE);
        // Check username dan password compare dengan databas
        }else{
            $i              = $this->input;
            $username       = $i->post('username');
            $password       = $i->post('password');
            // Check di database
            $check_login    = $this->user_model->login($username, $password);
            // Kalau ada record, maka create session dan redirect ke halaman dasbor
            if(count($check_login) == 1) {
                $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
                $this->session->set_userdata('akses_level', $check_login->akses_level);
                $this->session->set_userdata('id_user', $check_login->id_user);
                $this->session->set_userdata('nama', $check_login->nama);
                redirect(base_url('admin/dasbor'),'refresh');
            }else{
                // Kalau username password tidak cocok, error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('sukses', 'Username atau password tidak cocok');
                redirect(base_url('login'),'refresh');
            }
        }
        //End checking
    }

    // Logout
    public function logout() {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('username');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('akses_level');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('id_user');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('nama');
        // $this->session->set_flashdata('sukses', 'Anda berhasil logout');
        redirect(base_url('login'),'refresh');
    }

}

/* End of file Login.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/Login.php */
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use phpmailer libaray to send verfication link to using smtp mail like(gmail and localhost mail) and you can also create template for email with html